# Require a field in symfony2 server side

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

I have a form in Symfony2 which I am building with buildForm
I add constraints like so,

```
$builder
->add('firstName', 'text', [
        'required' => true,
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(),
        ],
    ]
)
```

Everything works fine until I delete the input from my html and submit it without the firstName. I don't get any errors and it submits normally. Is there a way to absolutely require the firstName, even if is not present in the submit data

Comment: You might want to add the controller code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an assert with your entity as explained in the [symfony documentation here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/validation.html)

like this:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @orm:Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     * @assert:NotBlank
     */
    private $firstname;
}
```

Comment: When making different asserts it is only checked when the input is in the submitted data field. I want to require the form to contain a certain field to be present in the submit data. After that it will validate normally with asserts.

Comment: don't forget to indicate "nullable=false" in the properties of your entity's $firstname field.

Answer (score 0):

You did not submit any data, the form is not submitted hence no validation is triggered.

Instead of:

```
$this->handleRequest($request);
```

Try to always submit the form even if the data is missing:

```
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```

*I cannot guarantee this code is valid in your context since you did not provide your controller code.*